# C# create JSON from TextBox and monthCalendar

Tags: c#, json, windows-forms-designer

Now I have a WindowsForm with a textbox and a calendar, and two buttons (continue and finish). 
The user has to enter a Text to the box and select a date. 
If he presses continue, the text and the date have to be written to a json file.
Then, the same window should open again and he can enter new values.
Finally, if he`s clicking the finish button, the Values should be written to the file and the window can close. 
(User should click finish already after he entered the first value).
I already created a get/set class:

```
class Nachrichten_Felder
{
    public string Nachrichten { get; set; }
    public string Datum { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this job? I really don`t know how to write the text and date to the json and reopen the window again...

For C# I use JSON.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made homework for you.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            var newsButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Show" };
            newsButton.Click += NewsButton_Click;
        }
        private void NewsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result;
            do
            {
                using (var newsForm = new NewsForm())
                    result = newsForm.ShowDialog();
            } while (result == DialogResult.OK);
        }
    }
    class NewsForm : Form
    {
        TextBox newsTextBox;
        MonthCalendar monthCalendar;
        Button continueButton;
        Button finishButton;

        Nachrichten_Felder news;

        public NewsForm()
        {
            Width = 400;

            newsTextBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Multiline = true, Size = new Size(200, 200) };
            monthCalendar = new MonthCalendar { Parent = this, Location = new Point(220, 0), MaxSelectionCount = 1 };
            continueButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Continue", Location = new Point(200, 220), DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
            finishButton = new Button { Parent = this, Text = "Finish", Location = new Point(300, 220), DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel };

            news = new Nachrichten_Felder();
            newsTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", news, "Nachrichten");
            monthCalendar.DataBindings.Add("SelectionStart", news, "Datum");

            this.FormClosing += NewsForm_FormClosing;
        }

        private void NewsForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(news, Formatting.Indented);
            File.AppendAllText(@"news.txt", json);
        }
    }
    class Nachrichten_Felder
    {
        public string Nachrichten { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Don`t know what to say apart from "thank you!" :)

Comment: B- the json is not properly formatted only one root is allowed! `List<Nachrichten_Felder> data = File.Exists("news.json") ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Nachrichten_Felder>>(File.ReadAllText("news.json")):new List<Nachrichten_Felder>();
            data.Add(news);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            File.WriteAllText(@"news.json", json);`